# Vue Router handling links present inside of v-html directive properly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I'm using Vue 3 (without TS) and Vue Router 4.

I have some markdown I get from my API that I parse with `markdown-it`, and then feed to a component via the `v-html` directive. The parsing itself works fine, everything shows up as it should, but if I have an `<a>` tag pointing to a route from inside the application, it's obviously not being handled as a proper `<router-link>`, so it forces a page refresh, which I'd obviously like to avoid.

Is there a way for me to handle internal links and have the `v-html` render it via `router-link`, so that it properly navigates as it should?

My component is dead simple

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <span v-html="content"></span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { parseMarkdown } from "../../helpers/markdownParser";

  export default {
    name: "BlogPost",
    data() {
      return {
        slug: undefined,
        title: null,
        content: null,
      };
    },
    async beforeCreate() {
      this.slug = this.$route.params.slug;

      await this.$axios.get(`/posts/${this.slug}`).then((response) => {
        const data = response.data[0];

        this.title = data.title;
        this.content = parseMarkdown(data.content);
      });
    },
  };
</script>
```

The `parseMarkdown` helper method simply invokes `markdown-it` and returns the parsed markdown as a string.

`markdownParser.js`

```js
import MarkdownIt from "markdown-it";

export const parseMarkdown = (html) => {
  return markdown.render(html);
};
```

Alternatively, is there another way other than `v-html` for me to get the parsed Markdown onto the page?

EDIT: To clarify what I get back from `parseMarkdown()`.

Sample markdown:

````markdown
# Example File

This is an **example** of what `markdown-it` does with the file.

[Links work](https://example.com), too. Though [internal links](/example) don't work quite as expected.

    ```html
    <p>We can also have codeblocks in our markdown</p>
    ```
````

What `markdown-it` gives back

```html
<h1>Example File</h1>

<p>This is an <strong>example</strong> of what <code>markdown-it</code> does with the file.</p>

<p><a href="https://example.com">Links work</a>, too. Though <a href="/example">internal links</a> don't work quite as expected.</p>

<pre><code class="lang-html">
  &lt;p&gt;
    We can also have codeblocks in our markdown
  &lt;/p&gt;
</code></pre>
```

Comment: you could switch out the `<a>`'s for `<router-link>`'s with DOMParser, then use a runtime compiler [*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/v-runtime-template) so <router-link> or any other component you add to the markdown works

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem by displaying HTML create outside the Vue app and downloaded from an API.

So I added a click event on the HTML container DIV:

```
<div v-html="body" @click.prevent="click"></div>
```

And then added a method that checks if the click was on a A tag and than pushes the path on the router.

```
methods: {
    click(ev) {
        if (ev.target.tagName === "A") {
            this.$router.push(new URL(ev.target.href).pathname);
        }
    },
},
```

Probably not the most elegant solution, but it's simple, worked for me and no other npm package is needed.